# Trouble using PHP data in separate file with getJSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, getjson

I have an array created in `wos.php` which I then `json_encode` and `echo` to use in another file, `data.php`, using jQuery.  The data is not being picked up for some reason.

This is an example of the array (`$recordArray`) created in `wos.php`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
           (
               [author1] => QIN, JUN-SHENG
               [citations] => 61
           )
    [1] => Array
           (
               [author1] => KOHANE, DANIELS
               [citations] => 60
           )
    [2] ...etc...
```

This is what the data looks like after I perform `echo json_encode($recordArray)`:

```
[
    {
        "author1" : "QIN, JUN-SHENG",
        "citations" : "61"
    },
    {
        "author1" : "KOHANE, DANIELS",
        "citations" : "60"
    }, ...etc...
```

Which all appears to be in the correct format.  This data is then used in `data.php` where it is displayed in a bar graph using jQuery/D3.  Here is a snippet of that code up to the point it is supposed to read the data from `wos.php` using `getJSON`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Academic Intelligence</title>
    ...etc...
</head>
<body>
    ...etc...
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // this is just so I know it has reached this point
        console.log("Works to here...");

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $.getJSON('wos.php', function(data) {

            alert(data);

            ...code that uses data to with D3 to display a bar graph...

            }
        }
    </script>
    ...etc...
</body>
</html>
```

The `console.log` prints "Works to here..." just before the jQuery, but `alert(data)` returns nothing so it's obviously failing to pick up the data.  Can anyone see why this fails?

I know the rest of the code works as I used to save the JSON data to a file in `wos.php` using `file_put_contents('data.json', json_encode($recordArray)` and then read that file in `data.php` with `$.getJSON('data.json', function(data)`.  This displayed the bar graph correctly and worked fine but is obviously not a good solution to be saving to and reading from the server, which is why I'm trying to AJAX it instead.

**** ADDITIONAL ****

Full code for `wos.php` as requested:

```
<?php

// TIMING INITIALISE
$mtime = microtime();
$mtime = explode(" ",$mtime);
$mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
$starttime = $mtime; 


// set processing time for browser before timeout
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600);
// override default PHP memory limit
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

// ensures anything dumped out will be caught, output buffer
ob_start();

// set WSDL for authentication and create new SOAP client
$auth_url  = "http://search.webofknowledge.com/esti/wokmws/ws/WOKMWSAuthenticate?wsdl";
// array options are temporary and used to track request & response data in printout below (line 65)
$auth_client = @new SoapClient($auth_url, array(
                 "trace" => 1,
                 "exceptions" => 0));
// run 'authenticate' method and store as variable
$auth_response = $auth_client->authenticate();

// set WSDL for search and create new SOAP client
$search_url = "http://search.webofknowledge.com/esti/wokmws/ws/WokSearch?wsdl";
// array options are temporary and used to track request & response data in printout below (line 130)
$search_client = @new SoapClient($search_url, array(
                 "trace" => 1,
                 "exceptions" => 0));
// call 'setCookie' method on '$search_client' storing SID (Session ID) as the response (value) given from the 'authenticate' method
$search_client->__setCookie('SID',$auth_response->return);


// =================================================================== //
// ============== PASS IN PARAMETERS FOR SOAP REQUEST ================ //
// =================================================================== //

// data passed in from user via form in index.html

// search type for journals (publication name)
$queryType1 = "SO";
// keyword(s)
$queryJournal1 = $_POST["journal1"];

// check if journal2 field has been populated, if not entered then set to blank
if (!$_POST["journal2"]) {
    $queryJournal2 = "";
} else {
    $queryJournal2 = $_POST["journal2"];
    $queryJournal2 = " OR " .$queryType1. "=" .$queryJournal2;
}

// check if journal3 field has been populated
if (!$_POST["journal3"]) {
    $queryJournal3 = "";
} else {
    $queryJournal3 = $_POST["journal3"];
    $queryJournal3 = " OR " .$queryType1. "=" .$queryJournal3;
}

// search type for titles
$queryType2 = "TI";
// keyword(s)
$queryTitle1 = $_POST["title1"];

// check if title2 field has been populated
if (!$_POST["title2"]) {
    $queryTitle2 = "";
} else {
    $queryTitle2 = $_POST["title2"];
    $queryTitle2 = " OR " .$queryType2. "=" .$queryTitle2;
}

// check if title3 field has been populated
if (!$_POST["title3"]) {
    $queryTitle3 = "";
} else {
    $queryTitle3 = $_POST["title3"];
    $queryTitle3 = " OR " .$queryType2. "=" .$queryTitle3;
}

// sort type
$sortType = "TC";

// check if timespan fields have been populated
if (!$_POST["timeStart"]) {
    $timeStart = "1864-01-01";
    $timeEnd = "2080-01-01";
} else {
    $timeStart = $_POST["timeStart"];
    $timeEnd = $_POST["timeEnd"];
}

// create an array to store all the search parameters to pass to data.html to display with the graph
$searchParams = array('journal1' => $queryJournal1,
                      'journal2' => $queryJournal2,
                      'journal3' => $queryJournal3,
                      'title1' => $queryTitle1,
                      'title2' => $queryTitle2,
                      'title3' => $queryTitle3,
                      'from' => $timeStart,
                      'to' => $timeEnd,
                     );

// turn top cited authors data into JSON file for displaying with JavaScript in data.html
// file_put_contents('search.json', json_encode($searchParams));

// pass in relevant parameters for search, this is the format necessary for Web of Science Web Service
$search_array = array(
    'queryParameters' => array(
        'databaseId' => 'WOS',
        'userQuery' => $queryType1.'='.$queryJournal1 . $queryJournal2 . $queryJournal3 . ' AND ' .$queryType2. '=' .$queryTitle1 . $queryTitle2 . $queryTitle3,
        'editions' => array('collection' => 'WOS', 'edition' => 'SCI'),
        'timeSpan' => array('begin' => $timeStart, 'end' => $timeEnd),
        'queryLanguage' => 'en'
    ),
    'retrieveParameters' => array(
        'count' => '100',
        'sortField' => array(
            array('name' => $sortType, 'sort' => 'D')
        ),
        'firstRecord' => '1'
    )
);


// =================================================================== //
// ======== PERFORM SEARCH USING PARAMETERS & SOAP CLIENT ============ //
// =================================================================== //


// try to store as a variable the 'search' method on the '$search_array' called on the SOAP client with associated SID 
try {
    $search_response = $search_client->search($search_array);
} catch (Exception $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
};

// number of records found by search, used to finish loop
$len = $search_response->return->recordsFound;

echo "</br>RECORDS FOUND: </br>";
print "<pre>\n";
print $len;
print "</pre>";


// =================================================================== //
// ============ CREATE VARIABLES TO STORE REQUIRED DATA ============== //
// ================== FROM XML & DISPLAY IN TABLE ==================== //
// =================================================================== //


// create an array to store data for each record per iteration
$recordArray = array();
// create an array to represent citation values to ignore, i.e. not interested in any publications with less than 4 citations
$ignore = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4);

// iterate through all records, perform search for each 100 records and tabulate data
for ($i = 1; $i <= $len; $i+=100) {

    // set search parameters for current iteration (first record = 1, 101, 201, 301 etc.)
    $search_array = array(
        'queryParameters' => array(
            'databaseId' => 'WOS',
            'userQuery' => $queryType1.'='.$queryJournal1 . $queryJournal2 . $queryJournal3 . ' AND ' .$queryType2. '=' .$queryTitle1 . $queryTitle2 . $queryTitle3,
            'editions' => array('collection' => 'WOS', 'edition' => 'SCI'),
            'timeSpan' => array('begin' => $timeStart, 'end' => $timeEnd),
            'queryLanguage' => 'en'
        ),
        'retrieveParameters' => array(
            'count' => '100',
            'sortField' => array(
                array('name' => $sortType, 'sort' => 'D')
            ),
            'firstRecord' => $i
        )
    );

    // gather search response for current iteration
    try {
        $search_response = $search_client->search($search_array);
    } catch (Exception $e) {  
        echo $e->getMessage(); 
    };

    // turn Soap Client object from current response into SimpleXMLElement
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($search_response->return->records);

    // save variable names for global use
    $author1 = "";
    // $author2 = "";
    // $author3 = "";
    $citations = "";

    // iterate through current data set and tabulate onto webpage plus store in variable
    foreach($xml->REC as $record) {
        // first author
        $author1 = (string)$record->static_data->summary->names->name[0]->full_name;
        // second author
        /* if (isset($record->static_data->summary->names->name[1]->full_name)) {
            $author2 = (string)$record->static_data->summary->names->name[1]->full_name;
            echo '<td>'.$author2.'</td>';
        } else {
            echo '<td>'."no record".'</td>';
            $author2 = "no record";
        }
        // third author
        if (isset($record->static_data->summary->names->name[2]->full_name)) {
            $author3 = (string)$record->static_data->summary->names->name[2]->full_name;
            echo '<td>'.$author3.'</td>';
        } else {
            echo '<td>'."no record".'</td>';
            $author3 = "no record";
        } */
        // number of citations, if zero then finish populating array then 'break' out of loop entirely (not interested in zero cited records)
        if (!in_array($record->dynamic_data->citation_related->tc_list->silo_tc->attributes(), $ignore)) {
            $citations = (string)$record->dynamic_data->citation_related->tc_list->silo_tc->attributes();
        } else {
            break 2;
        };

        // for this iteration map all the values recorded into a temporary array variable, aRecord (equivalent to one row of data in table)
        $arecord = array("author1"=>strtoupper($author1),
                         // "author2"=>$author2,
                         // "author3"=>$author3,
                         "citations"=>$citations
                        );

        // pass the data from this iteration into the array variable '$recordArray', after all iterations, each element in $recordArray will be a single record or row of data for a single journal
        array_push($recordArray, $arecord) ;
    }
};    

// need to replace single quotes in text to avoid escaping when inserting to mysql, and other charas to help remove duplicates
for ($i = 0; $i < count($recordArray); $i++) {
    $recordArray[$i]['author1'] = str_replace("'", " ", $recordArray[$i]['author1']);
    $recordArray[$i]['author1'] = str_replace(".", "", $recordArray[$i]['author1']);
    $recordArray[$i]['author1'] = str_replace(". ", "", $recordArray[$i]['author1']);
    $recordArray[$i]['author1'] = str_replace(" ", "", $recordArray[$i]['author1']);
    // $recordArray[$i]['author2'] = str_replace("'", " ", $recordArray[$i]['author2']);
    // $recordArray[$i]['author3'] = str_replace("'", " ", $recordArray[$i]['author3']);
}

echo "</br>RETRIEVED DATA: </br>";
print "<pre>\n";
print_r($recordArray);
print "</pre>";

// as length of $j loop will decrease each time because of 'unset' its elements, create a variable to dynamically store its length
$length = count($recordArray);
$count = 0;

// iterate each author in $recordArray, ignore last value otherwise would end up comparing it to itself in inner loop
for ($i = 0; $i < (count($recordArray) - 1); $i++) {
    // iterate each author in $recordArray a step ahead of the outer loop, compare each author with every other author in array
    for ($j = ($i + 1); $j < $length; $j++) {
        // if there is a match between author names then (@ignores undefined offset error occuring due to 'unset'):
        if ($recordArray[$i]['author1'] === $recordArray[$j]['author1']) {
            // add second citations value to first
            $recordArray[$i]['citations'] += $recordArray[$j]['citations'];
            // remove second instance
            unset($recordArray[$j]);
            // add to a variable the number of times 'unset' has been used for this iteration of $i
            $count++;
        }; // end if
    }; // end inner loop ($j)
    // decrease length of inner loop by $count, i.e. the number of elements that were removed in the last iteration, to make the length of the inner loop correct
    $length -= $count;
    // reset $count for next iteration of $i
    $count = 0;
    // reset indices
    $recordArray = array_values($recordArray);
}; // end outer loop ($i)

// sort array according to citation values
// make sure that data is sorted correctly (citations_sum, high -> low)
usort($recordArray, function ($a, $b) {
    return $b['citations'] - $a['citations'];
});

// only include first ten elements in array
$recordArray = array_slice($recordArray, 0, 10);

// make sure all the values are strings, when encoding the summed ints seem to cause problems
for ($i = 0; $i < (count($recordArray)); $i++) {
    $recordArray[$i]['citations'] = (string)$recordArray[$i]['citations'];
};

echo "</br>FINAL DATA: </br>";
print "<pre>\n";
print_r($recordArray);
print "</pre>";

// turn top cited authors data into JSON file for displaying with JavaScript
// file_put_contents('data.json', json_encode($recordArray));

// clear the output buffer
while (ob_get_status()) {
    ob_end_clean();
}

header("Location: data.php");
// include "data.php";

// output $recordArray in JSON format to be picked up by JavaScript in data.php
echo json_encode($recordArray);

// =================================================== //
// ================ TIMING END ======================= //
// =================================================== //


$mtime = microtime();
$mtime = explode(" ",$mtime);
$mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
$endtime = $mtime;
$totaltime = ($endtime - $starttime);
echo "This page was created in ".$totaltime." seconds";

?>
```

**** ADDITIONAL ****

Full code for `data.php` as requested:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>

<!-- BREADCRUMBS -->
<div class="sg-orientation">    
    <a href="#content" class="sg-button sg-skiptocontent">Skip to Content</a>
    <span class="sg-breadcrumbs">
        <a href="http://www.ncl.ac.uk/">Newcastle University</a> &gt;&gt;
        <a href="https://resviz.ncl.ac.uk/">Research Visualisation</a> &gt;&gt;
        <strong href="#">Academic Intelligence</strong>
    </span>
</div>

<!-- TITLE BAR -->
<div class="sg-titlebar">
    <h1><a title="Newcastle University Homepage" accesskey="1" href="http://www.ncl.ac.uk/"/><span title="Newcastle University">Newcastle University</span></a></h1>
    <h2><a href="https://resviz.ncl.ac.uk/wos/">Academic Intelligence</a></h2>
</div> 


<div class="sg-navigation">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="sg-content">

    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="https://resviz.ncl.ac.uk/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://resviz.ncl.ac.uk/chords/">Research Visualisation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Academic Intelligence</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!-- navbar-collapse -->
        </div> <!-- container -->
    </nav> <!-- navbar -->

    <section class="container">
        <h1>Authors with Largest Number of Citations</h1>

        <div class="chart well bs-component"></div>

        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h2>Information</h2>
            <p>The y-axis represents the number of citations for publications for the author on the x-axis. Click on one of the bars to perform a search on name of the associated author in Google.</p>
            <p>Try to find these authors on <a href="https://uk.linkedin.com/">LinkedIn</a> or the <a href="http://gtr.rcuk.ac.uk/" id="mail">Gateway to Research</a> sites.</p>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            console.log("Works to here...");

            $(document).ready(function() {

                // call to 'data.json' created in wos.php
                $.getJSON('wos.php', function (data) {
                    alert(data);

                    // javascript variable to store json data
                    var topCited = data;

                    console.log(topCited);

                    // establish some margins for the graph area to avoid overlap with other HTML elements
                    var margin = {
                                    top: 30,
                                    right: 30,
                                    bottom: 180,
                                    left: 100
                                 };

                    // initiate variables for max width and height of canvas for chart, determine largest citation value for domain and scaling
                    // width, 10 bars at 75px each plus 3px padding
                    var height = 500;
                    var width = 870;

                    var maxY = topCited[0].citations;

                    // set scale to alter data set so that it fits well in the canvas space
                    // map the domain (actual data range) to the range (size of canvas)
                    var linearScale = d3.scale.linear()
                                              // 0 -> largest citations value
                                              .domain([0, maxY])
                                              // 0 -> 600
                                              .range([0, height]);

                    // create canvas for chart
                    var svgContainer = d3.select(".chart").append("svg")
                                                          .attr("width", width)
                                                          // max size from data set plus 20px margin
                                                          .attr("height", height + margin.bottom);


                    // create an SVG Grouped Element (<g>) to contain all the 'bars' of the graph
                    var barGroup = svgContainer.append("g")
                                               .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

                    // bind the data to SVG Rectangle elements
                    var bar = barGroup.selectAll("rect")
                                      .data(topCited)
                                      .enter()
                                      .append("rect")
                                      .attr("fill", "#7bafd4")
                                      // highlight each bar as you hover over it
                                      .on("mouseover", function () {
                                          d3.select(this)
                                            .attr("fill", "#003c71");   
                                      })
                                      // transition to remove highlight from bar
                                      .on("mouseout", function() {
                                          d3.select(this)
                                            .transition()
                                            .duration(250)
                                            .attr("fill", "#7bafd4");
                                      });

                    // set variable to store bar width + padding
                    var barWidth = 78;

                    // set attributes for the rectangles (bars)
                    var rectAttributes = bar.attr("width", 75)
                                            // set bar height by value of citations
                                            .attr("height", function (d) {
                                                return linearScale(d.citations);
                                            })
                                            // index * 78 will move each bar (width, 75px) one bar width along and leave 3px padding
                                            .attr("x", function (d, i) {
                                                return i * barWidth;
                                            })
                                            // this is determined from the top left corner so to get the bar at the bottom, take the bar height from the canvas height
                                            .attr("y", function (d) {
                                                return height - linearScale(d.citations);
                                            })

                    // bind the data to SVG Text elements
                    var text = barGroup.selectAll("text")
                                       .data(topCited)
                                       .enter()
                                       .append("text");

                    // set attributes for the text on bars (citation values)
                    var barLabels = text.attr("x", function (d, i) {
                                             return (barWidth * i) + 37.5; // sets to halfway between each bar horizontally
                                         })
                                         .attr("y", function (d) {
                                             return height - (linearScale(d.citations)) - 3; // sets to top of each bar + 5 to sit just above bar
                                         })
                                         .text(function (d) {
                                             return d.citations; // value to display, citations value (number)  
                                         })
                                         .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                                         .attr("font-family", "Raleway")
                                         .attr("font-size", "26px")
                                         .attr("fill", "#7bafd4");

                    // create a scale for the horizontal axis
                    var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
                                         .domain(data.map(function (d) {
                                            return d.author1;
                                         }))
                                         .rangeRoundBands([0, 780], 0);

                    // create a scale for the vertical axis
                    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                                         .domain([0, maxY])
                                         .range([height, 0]);

                    // define x-axis
                    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                                      .scale(xScale)
                                      .orient("bottom")
                                      .ticks(10);

                    // define y-axis
                    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                                  .scale(yScale)
                                  .orient("left")
                                  .ticks(10);

                    // if this calculation is done in "translate" below, it concatenates instead of adding values
                    var translateY = height + margin.top;

                    // create x-axis
                    svgContainer.append("g")
                                .attr("class", "axis")
                                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + translateY + ")")
                                .call(xAxis)
                                // select author names
                                .selectAll("text")
                                .attr("font-family", "Lora")
                                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                                // spacing
                                .attr("dx", "-.8em")
                                .attr("dy", ".15em")
                                // rotate text as too long to display horizontally
                                .attr("transform", function (d) {
                                    return "rotate(-45)";
                                });

                    // create y-axis
                    svgContainer.append("g")
                                .attr("class", "axis")
                                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left  + "," + margin.top + ")")
                                .call(yAxis)
                                // append a title to the y-axis
                                .append("text")
                                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                                .attr("y", -70)
                                .attr("x", -200)
                                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                                .attr("fill", "#000")
                                .attr("font-family", "Lora")
                                .attr("font-size", "24px")
                                .text("Citations");

                    // create link when user clicks on a single bar of data
                    d3.selectAll("rect")
                      .on("click", function (d) {
                          // variable stores url for google and adds author name relevant to bar that was clicked
                          var url = "https://www.google.co.uk/#q=" + d.author1;
                          // add an href html element with the url attached
                          $(location).attr("href", url);
                          window.location = url;
                      });
                })
            });

        </script>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <h3>Temporary Graph is Temporary</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-7"></div>
        </div> <!-- row -->

        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <tbody id="searchData"></tbody>
        </table>

    </section> <!-- container -->

</div> <!-- sg-content -->

<!-- FOOTER -->
<div class="sg-clear">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="sg-footer">
    <p><a href="http://www.ncl.ac.uk/res/about/office/research/">Research &amp; Enterprise Services</a><br/>Newcastle University, Newcastle Upon Tyne,<br/>NE1 7RU, United Kingdom<br/><a href="mailto:res.policy@ncl.ac.uk">Email Webmaster</a><br/><br/>&copy; 2014 Newcastle University</p>
</div>

<!-- bootstrap js -->
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- check browser version, if outdates, prompt for update -->
<script src="//browser-update.org/update.js"></script>
```

**** ADDITIONAL ****

Full code for `index.php` as requested:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

```
<head>
</head>

<body>
        <!-- main content -->
        <section class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- search params -->
                <form action="wos.php" method="post" role="form" class="form-horizontal" id="form">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-6 well bs-component">

                                <div class="journal_fields_wrap">
                                    <!-- keyword(s) for journal name(s) -->
                                    <label>Journal Title</label>
                                    <a class="btn btn-success" id="journal_list" target="_blank" href="http://ip-science.thomsonreuters.com/cgi-bin/jrnlst/jlresults.cgi?PC=D">Journal List</a>
                                    <button class="add_journal_field_button btn btn-info" type="button">Add more fields</button>
                                    <div>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="journal1" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                               title="this is a tooltip">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="title_fields_wrap">
                                    <!-- keyword(s) for paper title(s) -->
                                    <label>Keyword</label>
                                    <button class="add_title_field_button btn btn-info" type="button">Add more fields</button>
                                    <div>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title1" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                               title="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- timespan -->
                                <label>TIMESPAN</label></br>
                                <label>From: <input class="form-control" type="date" name="timeStart" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"></label>
                                <label>To: <input class="form-control" type="date" name="timeEnd" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"></label><br/><br/>

                                <!-- execute search -->
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>

                            </div> <!-- col-lg-6 -->

                            <div class="col-lg-6 well bs-component">

                                <div class="jumbotron">
                                    <h1>How to..</h1>
                                    <p>Please enter only one journal title or keyword per box.</p>
                                    <p>If you would like further information on x, y and z, then please,
                                    <a class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" target="_blank" href="#">Click here</a></p>
                                </div>

                            </div> 

                        </div> <!-- form-group -->
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div> <!-- row -->

            <!-- TEMPORARY PLACEMENT FOR LOADING BAR -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <h3 style="color:red">Temporary progress bar is Temporary</h3>
                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                        <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 40%"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
            </div>

        </section> <!-- main content; container -->
    </div> <!-- sg-content -->

    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <div class="sg-clear">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="sg-footer">
        <p>Research &amp; Enterprise Services<br/>Newcastle University, Newcastle Upon Tyne,<br/>NE1 7RU, United Kingdom<br/><a href="mailto:res.policy@ncl.ac.uk">Email Webmaster</a><br/><br/>&copy; 2014 Newcastle University</p>
    </div>

    <!-- SCRIPTS -->

    <!-- jquery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- local script -->
    <script src="script.js"/></script>
    <!-- bootstrap js -->
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- angularJS -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!-- check browser version, if outdates, prompt for update -->
    <script src="//browser-update.org/update.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Check the console for errors in the network tab. You most likely have a 500 error on the server, so the success callback is never fired.

Comment: Got a bunch of 200 OK and 304 Not Modified.  `wos.php` is coming up with a 302 Found, so that all seems fine, I think..

Comment: Please show us the code of wos.php. What happens if you surf to wos.php in your browser?

Comment: @MarioA have added full code for `wos.php`.  If I surf to it in browser, the redirect automatically sends me to `data.php`.  If I take out the redirect, it displays the various bits of data I have printed out to the screen with `print_r`.  I use this to check that the data looks correct whilst being processed by PHP.

Comment: To explain function: there is a front end page `index.php` where user submits data to a form, this data is then processed with `wos.php` and the resulting data sent to `data.php` to display in a bar graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit confusing, but i think the reason is the redirect `header("Location: data.php")`

This tells the browser to request a the new page `data.php`. Because data.php is loaded in a new request, all variables and collected data is gone.

Solution:
Instead of `header` use `inlcude`.

```
include "data.php";
```

This way data.php is included on the server side, and variables and also the output buffer can be used for further processing.

In data.php no ajax call via `$.getJson` is necessary. Instead inject the json directly via php:

```
var data = $.parseJSON( '<?php echo json_encode($recordArray) ?>' );
alert(data);
```

Comment: Changed the line `header("Location: data.php")` to `include "data.php"` but no change, unfortunately, or error messages... Is there a better way to load `data.php` after it's finished processing `wos.php`?

Comment: Actually, there is a minor change, at the bottom of the page in the browser for `data.php` it includes the line `This page was created in ... seconds` from the timing part from `wos.php` (last line of code) - not sure if this helps pinpoint the problem?  It's not echoing any of the other data.

Comment: please put the echo json_encode($recordArray); beneath the ob_end_clean(), otherwise it will not be outputted, and remove the include "data.php"; entirely

Comment: Okay, I've moved the `json_encode` bit - that makes sense!

If I remove `header("Location: data.php")` then it goes no further than `wos.php` in the browser and just displays the JSON data from `echo json_encode($recordArray)`.

If I leave that in it prints the JSON data and displays the error message `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\academic_intelligence\public\wos.php:326)` which is the `json_encode` line.

`include "data.php"` was already removed.

Comment: Because my previous comment seemed confusing I've edited `wos.php` in the main question to reflect the changes I've made...

Comment: just remove the redirect with header(..) and directly surf to data.php in your browser. There wot.php is called separately via ajax, isn't it?

Comment: Problem is that user starts at `index.php` where they enter some search parameters into a form.  These are then POSTed to `wos.php` and further data is retrieved via a Web API.  This data is then processed and the final processed data ($recordArray) is passed to `data.php` to display in a bar graph with jQuery.  So if I go straight to `data.php` I'm not posting any of the necessary search parameters into the form on `index.php`.  I'll put code for `index.php` above...

Comment: Was running out of space in question so have added `index.php` but deleted all the `<head>` data from all files as it's irrelevant to this problem

Comment: understand. But in this case no redirect is necessary. Use include as in my answer above. Output the json array directly in data.php instead in wos.php. I updated my answer above.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean, have tried that but now it's saying that recordArray is an undefined variable in `data.php`...

Answer (score 1):

PHP code you wrote might be giving error.

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'
```

You can open apache error log and find it there eg: /var/log/apache/error.log

And if you change your php code as shown below should fix the issue

```
$recordArray = Array(0 => Array("author1" => "QIN, JUN-SHENG","citations" => 61),1 => Array("author1" => "KOHANE, DANIELS","citations" => 60));
```

Thanks

Comment: No PHP parse errors in either Apache or PHP error logs.I'm not creating the array manually from scratch, it is created by iterating a SOAP Response object and storing the necessary XML elements to a multi-dimensional array.  So the array format is set automatically by PHP.

Comment: Did you try $.ajax ?  Please try this, in your case $.Ajax is better.  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Doesn't work either, unfortunately.  That is assuming that the `$.ajax` equivalent would be:
    `$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "wos.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
    ...etc...
    }
    });`